# Query Error - cannot convert nvarchar

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, sqlserver, sql

I am trying to return details associated with a certain email address . I am using the query below:

```
select emailaddress
,subscriberkey
,record_type_name__c
from

mastersubscriberde

where emailaddress ='xxx@email.com'
```

I am getting this error when i run it in Automation Studio:

> Query failed during execution. Error: Conversion failed when
>   converting the nvarchar value 'xxx@email.com' to data type
>   int.

I will appreciate any pointers on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had mistakenly set the data type of on 'emailaddress' as number. Changing it to email sorted it out.